# Phusion Passenger not displaying CSS, Javascript files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, apache, passenger, phusion

I have a Phusion install, configured with Rails 3.0.10 and Apache 2, and assets like CSS and Javascript are apparently being served, but not utilized by the browser.

So for instance when I hit the root url, the page renders, but CSS and javascripts are not used by the browser.  I see GET requests coming through for each asset in the access logs.

I can visit those assets directly in my browser, going to stylesheets/application.css?1313636333 I see the correct application.css

I dont see permission errors in production logs, or apache error logs.

My VHost looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin info@example.com
  ServerName portal.example.com
  DocumentRoot /app/example/public
  <Directory /app/example/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think I had an error similar to this. What does the relevant portion of routes.rb look like?

Comment: root :to => "sites#index"  ...just requesting the root url.  All of the various assets like under public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can access your static assets, the mime-type incorrectness might be the cause.

Take the output of the following:

```
curl --head http://portal.example.com/stylesheets/application.css
```

the result should contains "Content-Type: text/css"

Comment: Good suggestion.  Unfortunately yes it returns content type text/css

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2011 19:33:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Aug 2011 02:58:53 GMT
ETag: "17f5a9-441-4aabecb087a21"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1089
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/css

Comment: Try using your browsers debugging function to trace network activities

Comment: It turned out it was some SASS/Flutie issue.  Couldn't pinpoint it but looking at a good version locally and blowing away all of the SASS mumbo jumbo fixed it.  Thanks for everyones suggestions